# iOS Swift Time Based Line Draw

Tags: ios, swift, draw

I want to draw almost like a racetrack shape as a black bar that draws itself over time.

I have not really worked with drawing stuff in iOS so I have no idea where to start.  Any help would be appreciated.

*Core Concept*: Draw a line in a racetrack shape over a time span.

Comment: http://oleb.net/blog/2010/12/animating-drawing-of-cgpath-with-cashapelayer/

Answer (score 0):

http://oleb.net/blog/2010/12/animating-drawing-of-cgpath-with-cashapelayer/

Did provide the solution, thank you luk2302